# When is it appropriate to use dynamic array as opposed to static array?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management, dynamic

Dynamic and static arrays: When both are possible, what's usually the rationale behind using one over the other?

---

One of the situations might be

```
int n;
cin >> n;
int a[n];
```

versus

```
int n;
cin >> n;
int* a = new int[n];
```

Comment: Well, `int a[n]` is an error in C++.

Comment: `int a[n]` is called variable length arrays, and is invalid, don't write them.

Comment: @melpomene, I can compile and run [this](https://pastebin.com/tW5KkNSC) without an error.

Comment: @HuXinqiao That's because compilers typically support not only standard C++, but also certain language extensions. When passed the right compiler flags (`-pedantic`/`-pedantic-errors` with GCC), such extensions will be warned about.

Comment: @HuXinqiao You're probably using gcc without warnings enabled.

Comment: @melpomene that's not the case, see my answer. `Wall` and `Wextra` didn't trigger the message.

Comment: @melpomene, hvd I see. My follow-up would be why is VLA undesirable, and I'll refer to the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard). Appreciate the help.

Comment: It is a good idea to use the flag `-pedantic-errors` to force the compiler to adhere to whatever standard you have configured it to use.

Comment: @gsamaras Oh, yeah. `-pedantic` (or `-Wpedantic` nowadays) is part of my standard flag set because it enables diagnostics required by the standard.

Answer (score 1):

`int a[n]` is a variable-length array, which is not allowed by the C++ standard, thus the second code snipper should be your option.

Use `-pedantic` flag, and you should get:

```
warning: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'a' [-Wvla]
     int a[n];
            ^
```

Answer (score 0):

As other answers pointed out, you semantics of a variable length array is invalid.  However, c++ does support dynamic length arrays via the Vector class, so your question still makes sense, just not with the syntax you used. I am going to interpret the question then as should you use Vectors or arrays. The answer is:

1)Use arrays when you don't need dynamic size or resizing *and* speed is critical *and* you are not concerned with the array index being out of bounds.

2)otherwise use vectors